# What methodology is best suited for Regression from text data?

Tags: python, text, scikit-learn, nlp

I have a bunch of sentences each associated with a numerical performance value.

I would like to do two things:

- Based on a new sentence predict performance
- Find out which words have the highest correlation with a high score

What's the best way to extract features from sentences? Can someone advise me one which model is best suited for the above and is available in Sklearn?

Thanks!
Charles

ps: Down the line the text input will be combined with other numerical features to predict performance.

EDIT: Text Samples:

> Barry is a Wonderful Host! His place is very nice and Barry is a very
>   kind & helping person. I will recommend him to all of my friends
>   travelling to Amsterdam for a short or long trip! The location of his
>   apartment is very convenient and can be easily accessed by tram. Just
>   a short  tram ride or a few minutes of walking or biking then we were
>   home. Thanks Barry for such a wonderful time! Wish u the best of luck
>   and thanks again!

Comment: It's unclear how your data looks like (provide an example table or smth), but I assume you have feature / outcome pairs where your feature is a sentence and the outcome is some continuous variable. In this case, you could transform your sentence in a set of binary variables by counting the occurrence  of specific words that you deem predictive. You can then use this as input to e.g. linear regression (though I am not sure how much sense linear regression would make in such a case, I am no expert on text mining).

Comment: I added a sample

Answer (score 4):

The basic premise of all data analysis of text to to convert the sentence into a vector in a fixed dimensional space, and do the regression there using your favorite method.  This can be done in a couple of ways:

### [Bag of words](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_extraction.html#the-bag-of-words-representation)

This is the "traditional" way to do this task. This will probably work better if you also stem the words, which can be done with [NLTK](http://www.nltk.org/).

### Deep learning

Neural networks have solved many tasks well recently. Text analysis is one of them. You could take a look at https://github.com/ryankiros/skip-thoughts, or find a RNN to convert your sentence into a vector. It is however very difficult to interpret these models, so finding which words correlate with a high score is difficult.